# isMatch() function not working correctly in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, image, matching

I am trying to use an empty array which fills when clicking on an image send the Image ID to a `findMatch()` function which in turn is used to insert the a match in a `isMatch()` function. My `isMatch()` function is not working correctly. I have tried debugging in Chrome but this is not helping. Any help or advice would be appreciated. I need to clear the array after 2 images are selected.

```js
function isMatch() {

  if ((count === 1) && (pic == 1)) {
    cMatch.unshift(arrMatch);
    match1 = imgID;
  }

  if ((count === 2) && (pic == 1)) {
    // var index2=deClick(clicked);
    cMatch.push(arrMatch);
    match2 = imgID; {
      if (cMatch[0] === cMatch[1]) {
        bMatch = true;

        cMatch.length = 0;
        cMatch = [];
        count = 0;
        match1 = 0;
        match2 = 0;
      } else {
        bMatch = false;
        document.getElementById(match1).src = defaultImage;
        document.getElementById(match2).src = defaultImage;

        cMatch.length = 0;
        cMatch = [];
        count = 0;
        match1 = 0;
        match2 = 0;
      }
      //else{bMatch=false;}}
    }
    if (count > 2) {
      document.getElementById(match1).src = defaultImage;
      document.getElementById(match2).src = defaultImage;
      count = 0;
      return bMatch;
    }

  }
}
```

The code when stepping in Chrome seems to work but when I use in the browser it does not work at all.

Comment: Do you receive any errors?

Comment: How does it not work exactly? What happens and what is supposed to happen? Can you post a [mcve] demonstrating the problem?

Comment: **bold**The isMatch is suppose to Flip images from an array of 6 duplicate image it comes from my tblArr which contains 12 images the isMatch is suppose to flip the images if they do not match and if I can figure out how to do it only make the matched images draggable and droppable on to a drop box. Now all images are draggable and droppable!!  For my full code see [link](https://codepen.io/babj/pen/WNNMKRY) which contains my CSS and JavaScript Files as well as the HTML. This version is separate file. I do not get any errors except an error on changeImage which works fine.